# Adding Foreign keys in Visual Studio Express 2012 for web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, foreign-keys

In Visual Web Developer Express 2012 there used to be an easy to use Diagram editor where one could add foreign key contraints, but that seems to be missing from the 2012 express edition unless I'm looking over it.

How can I add a foreign key contraint between two tables in the express edition of Visual Studio 2012 for web?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a relationship when you design your tables. Click on the column and it'll allow you to add one. It's changeable as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are right!!! The database designer seems to be absent from the Visual Studio Express 2012 Edition. I was also looking for a solution to that, and I found this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272695(v=VS.103).aspx

Be sure to look up the - 'To create new foreign key references using the Table Designer' section.